# css: How to horizontal align fonts with different sizes

Tags: html, css, font-size, alignment

first question on SO !

Im trying to "pixel perfect" horizontal align  two lines of text , each line with a different font-size.

```
<style type="text/css">
    *   { font-family: sans-serif;}
    div { float: left;}
    h1  { font-size: 150px;  margin-bottom:-30px; }
</style>

        <div>
            <h1> B </h1>
            <h6> B-L.align </h6>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1> L </h1>
            <h6> L.align </h6>
        </div>
```

sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/jgYBD/1/

If you look at the sample , you will notice that the larger font has more "?padding?" than the smaller font. making them misaligned by a few pixels.

Im looking for a way or formula to perfectly left align them ,without using trial and error on the margin-left!

All ideas are appreciated , thanks.

Comment: You're talking about the stuff below the big text, right? Well that would of course happen, each letter is a different width. The D is the largest with 108px. If you set the H1 to 108px in CSS, h1 { width: 108px } they will be exactly even then by being 108 px apart. will that help?

Comment: Do you need an automation to do this? If not, you could overcome this with simple try/fails using `text-indent` and `text-align:justify` to a single big letter `width`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is not padding, but some kind of "kerning" of the font.
Not really that, but sort of.
The big big problem about that is that it is different for every font, and even for every letter.
try  replacing the

```
<h1>B</h1>
```

by

```
<h1>J</h1>
```

now the space is much smaller !

this space depends of the font, the size and the letter. So, I don't think that you can control that

Comment: Thanks , that's the problem!! If could find a font with equal "kerning" on all characters , then it could be easy to figure out the relation between bigText and smallText  , and extrapolate the adjustment for any font-size combinations , but Google isn't helping on this ...

Comment: There are fonts like this, but I have never used them in the web. Look for "monospaced fonts", or "fixed width" fonts. The most widely known is "Courier". But what is constant is the width of the char, not the empty space to the left ...

Answer (score 3):

A potential trick: Add `:first-letter { margin-left: -0.08em; }`. The em has to be adjusted for your font, but you can apply it globally if you want. It does result in a small shift to the left, but you can change the font-size of the H1 with impunity and it stays aligned.

See this [update to your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgYBD/15/).

It doesn't fix the "J" issue though so it might be a moot point for you.

Answer (score 2):

as i understaind you u want this?:

```
h6 {
    float: left;
position: relative;
left: 11px;
}
```

sample here : http://jsfiddle.net/jgYBD/4/

Comment: Exactly ,thats the result i want ! But how do you get to "left: 11px;" ? Chrome and Firefox render my font differently and i was wondering if there is a trick to get the margins values right without a trial and error approach.

Comment: for best results use % instead of using px for font size. u can also ex. if u want to target mozila only

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
* { font-weight: 100; }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-weight: 400; /* 400 is the 'normal' font weight - which is pretty bold in Firefox! */ }
}

Comment: How does this fix the problem?  The 11px is just a guess.  If you change the font size of the header, it's misaligned again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`h6 { padding: 0 10px; }`

Comment: Doesn't work with bigger letters (eg, 300px), but it works with the example OP provided.

Comment: Yeah, he would have to get rid of the whitespace in the html and just use the padding.